# Would having people vote on the outcomes of multivariate tests keep people interested in UX?

Tags: usability, usability-testing, games, information

I'd like to get people at my company involved in usability testing by encouraging them to vote on the outcomes of multivariate tests.

A talk I saw at a conference a few weeks ago explained that this was a good way for people to understand more about usability testing and keep people interested in the work that we do.

Does anybody do this and find that it works well across their company? Are there any sites that I could use to create a voting system with screenshots?

Comment: You mean like having an office pool? I've got $2 on the hyperlink using the `blink` tag!

Comment: Yep, it sounds like a good idea to gamify A/B tests.

Comment: Nice idea. Gonna try it myself.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey : Which what odds are you willing to make that bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in a slightly low tech way before, sending a pair of screenshots of UI elements in an e-mail and simply asking for a reply of A or B. You could use [Survey Monkey](http://www.surveymonkey.com) or similar to ask for responses too.

It worked quite well, staff liked being asked for input on how the company website looked and felt, rather than being dictated too. Although I did find that the number of responses drops if you do it too often.

Also worth noting that your staff who are familiar with your products will assume things your customers/clients might not, so testing with people outside the bubble of your business is always a good idea too.

Comment: I like the low-tech approach, it's a good way to start before building something.